# Not able to add an apple account to the visual studio 2017

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, connection, account

I have an apple account with the admin role. Whenever I'm trying to add an apple account to visual studio, it displays "There was an error while trying to log in: A server with the specified hostname could not be found".
I updated Visual Studio 2017 also. Still, it displays the same error.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Firstly, please update your VS 2017 to the latest, then if this issue is still existed, Visual Studio 2019 for windows had released , you can try it. You must also have a paid Apple Developer account to use this feature.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=windows#requirements

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I upgraded visual studio 2017.It's not working. My apple account is not a paid account. But My account has an admin role in one paid team.is not enough to add my apple account to visual studio.
Is paid account mandatory to add in visual studio?
I don't know this information.please let me know once.

Comment: I do not have this kind of  account, so I cannot test it. But I added my account in the VS 15.9.21, I can add it.Do you use Proxy to connect public internet? If yes, please close it or change another network environment to make a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 and installed Visual Studio 2019.
Now I'm able to add an Apple account to my Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As @LeonLu mentioned, it might be a problem with the non-paid version of account.

This is stated in the Microsoft docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=macos

Comment: I tried with the account holder credentials also..It displays the same error to me.

Comment: I have one doubt..Is Two-factor authentication is mandatory..?
If Yes..for that my apple account not adding to visual studio 2017?

Comment: I personally use 2FA, but I'm not sure that's the issue here. I'll try connecting my Apple account to Visual Studio right now(it's not a paid developer account), and respond with the results:)

Comment: It worked for me with the 2FA. After inserting the email and password, I was asked to put in the 6-digit code which was sent to my Iphone.
Your error says that the hostname which I think is your Apple ID email was not found. Did you use the email that is defined at your Apple ID account (a dumb question but still haha)?