# Xamarin Deployment issues to IPAd

Tags: xamarin

I am keep getting Xamarin deployment issues to my IPAD. This is really starting to getting annoying. Xamarin really start to suck.
And the funny thing this used to work, here are some of the errors
Errors..Failed to obtain profile information from the build server. please check the connectivity with Mac built host.
No Valid IOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a code signing cert from https://developer.apple.com

[image]

Comment: Did you added the Ipad on your provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1):

Do you develop with VS 2017 ?

It is a known issue and the solution is that upgrade vs to 2019 .

Ref :

[Not able to add an apple account to the visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630616/not-able-to-add-an-apple-account-to-the-visual-studio-2017)

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/884189/adding-appleid-in-vs-2017-professional-15918.html

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/2377